Your new site design is live!
As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with design and bug). Thank you for your valuable design feedback and for your patience while we got this out for you.
We really hope you like the design! Thanks so much to Jose for his work on this!

The new style is fairly sweet at first sight!!
I've just seen it and felt I owed you this after harsh critiques a few months ago.
Keep up the good work!
